# Finding the angle at which a parametric curve intersects itself

Tags: calculus, parametric

I have a parametric curve, given by
$$
\gamma: \mathbb{R} \to  \mathbb{R}: t \mapsto 
\begin{bmatrix}
t^2-1 \\
t(t^2-1)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which intersects itself at the origin $(0,0)$. I have to find the **angle** at which this curve intersects itself, so naturally I would use the formula
$$
\cos \theta = \frac{\langle \dot{\gamma}_1(t_1)| \dot{\gamma}_2(t_2)\rangle}{||\dot{\gamma}_1(t_1)|| \,||\dot{\gamma}_2(t_2)||}, \quad \theta \in [0,\pi]
$$
that describes the intersection angle between two parametric curves, where, in this particular case, $\dot{\gamma}_1(t_1) = \dot{\gamma}_2(t_2) = \dot{\gamma} (t)$.
However, $\dot{\gamma} (t)$ is
$$
\dot{\gamma} (t) = \begin{bmatrix} 2t \\ 3t^2 -1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
and thus I get
$$ \begin{align}
\cos \theta &= \frac{\begin{bmatrix} 2t \\ 3t^2 -1 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 2t \\ 3t^2 -1 \end{bmatrix}}{||\begin{bmatrix} 2t \\ 3t^2 -1 \end{bmatrix}||\cdot||\begin{bmatrix} 2t \\ 3t^2 -1 \end{bmatrix}||} \\
&= \frac{(2t)^2 + (3t^2-1)^2}{\sqrt{(2t)^2 + (3t^2-1)^2} \cdot \sqrt{(2t)^2 + (3t^2-1)^2}} \\
&= 1
\end{align}
$$
which gives an angle of $\theta = 0 \,\mathrm{rad}$ via $\arccos{1} = 0$. As we can see from [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametric%20plot%20((t%5E2-1),(t(t%5E2-1))) this can't be correct (my initial guess would've been $\pi/2$ rad). Where did I go wrong here? It's probably some stupid sloppy mistake...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calculating the angle using the same vector. Obviously, the angle between a vector and itself is $0$. Instead, you should look at which values of $t$ it happens $\gamma(t) = 0$. It's clear that curve $\gamma$ only touches $0$ twice, once for $t_1 = -1$ and then for $t_2 = 1$. You should use the formula that provides the angle for vectors $\dot{\gamma}(-1)$ and $\dot{\gamma}(1)$.

Comment: Wow. I literally facepalmed myself right now. I was so hellbent on this "curve intersects itself" that I didn't think about the loop it makes (that changes $t$) before intersecting. I'll accept your answer ASAP. Many thanks for the help!

Comment: And of course the scalar product in the numerator then becomes $[-2,2] \cdot [2,2] = 0$, which makes the whole expression $0$, yielding $\theta = \pi/2$.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve without vectors.

The parametrics have an easy elimination of parameter $t$ which gives the nodal cubic of cartesian equation $$y^2=(x+1)x^2$$ so the derivative is
$$2ydy=(x^2+2x(x+1))dx\Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{3x^2+2x}{2x\sqrt{x+1}}$$ The value of this derivative at $x=0$ has the form $\frac 00$ so applying l'Hôpital Rule we get the form $$\frac{6x+2}{2\sqrt{x+1}+\frac{x}{\sqrt{x+1}}}$$ which have the determined value $1$ when $x=0$ and clearly $-1$ for the other negative value of $y=\pm x\sqrt{x+1}$.

Thus the searched angle is $90^{\circ}$.